# postgres 15.1 : permission denied for schema public

Tags: postgresql, privileges

This is what I did as superuser:

```
demo02=> create user pippo;
demo02=> GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE demo02 TO pippo;
demo02=> GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO pippo;
```

and then I connected as pippo:

C:\Users\Aldo>psql -U pippo demo02

and tried to create a table, but got this:

```
demo02=>     create table book (
demo02(>        id int8 not null,
demo02(>         book_name varchar(255) not null,
demo02(>         created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE not null,
demo02(>         student_id int8 not null,
demo02(>         primary key (id)
demo02(>     );
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: create table book (
                     ^
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setup new user and database on a new Postgresql 15 server, but no permission to create table in public schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977244/setup-new-user-and-database-on-a-new-postgresql-15-server-but-no-permission-to)

Comment: Ahhh... Yes, this sentence answered my question: "I was on the wrong database when executing the command. It works now. I connected using psql -d exampledomain then executed the command "... Does it mean that in postgres 15 there is no one-line-commad to add ALL privileges on ALL databases to a user?

Comment: only the options mentioned here are accepted: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-grant.html